# How to force Sent, Draft, and Spam folders to be listed at the top with Inbox at Evolution

Tags: email, evolution

The only folder that breaks the alphabetical order in my Evolution (3.45.3-2) is my **Inbox* folder.

I would like to have all other special folders (Sent, Draft, and Spam) just below the Inbox and then all other folders would continue with the alphabetical ordering.

The question is: How to move folders **sent**, **draft**, and **spam** to be right below the Inbox folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The easy way

To reorganize the folder is to use the Evolution's `Folder`|`Edit Sort Order`.  (This will create a `~/.config/evolution/mail/folder-tweaks.ini` file)

### The manual (hard) way

If you have never sorted your email folders before the file `~/.config/evolution/mail/folder-tweaks.ini` will not exist.
First you need to create the `folder-tweaks.ini` in the `~/.config/evolution/mail/` path.  Next you need to take the Folder Ids from the `state.ini` and place them into the `folder-tweaks.ini` folder with the `Sort=1` option.

Taken from actual file:

```
[folder://cb63dac0c165a656a90c34f41a644a0bb77dba65/INBOX]
Sort=1
[folder://cb63dac0c165a656a90c34f41a644a0bb77dba65/Sent]
Sort=2
[folder://cb63dac0c165a656a90c34f41a644a0bb77dba65/sent]
Sort=3
...
```

The id: `cb63dac0c165a656a90c34f41a644a0bb77dba65` identifies uniquely the inbox.

The original post about this is at:
[Rearranging Email Folders in Evolution](https://askubuntu.com/a/1371680/963426):

> Folders can be edited by adding a `Sort` property to
> `~/.config/evolution/mail/folder-tweaks.ini`.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> [folder://0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567/INBOX]  
> Sort=1
>
> [folder://0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567/GitHub]  
> Sort=2
>
> [folder://0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567/GitLab]  
> Sort=3
> ```
>
> The order of sections doesn’t matter, but they can be rearranged to
> match your sorting order.

Comment: Thank you, you search-fu is better than mine. I'll test it and let you know.

Comment: I have edited your answer to be correct.  The posted answer is only partial and it does not show the "proper" (gui) way to do it.  After the edit will be accepted I'll accept the answer.

Comment: Nicely done - I have approved your edit.